# Start a node server on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS. I am trying to start to a Node server to fetch the data from the database. As we use command `node script.js` to start the node server. Could please anyone guide me on how to upload and run the script over AWS servers.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried https://pm2.keymetrics.io/ ?

Comment: Yea, it's fine to run the server permanently. But how to upload the file over the AWS server and then, use this command to run it over that server?

Comment: Here is a tutorial to upload in aws https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c

Comment: Everything works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the original link provided in the comments by @Shahadat Hossain,

Here is a tutorial to upload in aws:

https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c